# Facebook Graph API: Get list of albums of a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the list of albums of a friend using the Graph API. Using the Graph API Explorer, I do the following:

- Get Access Token, logging in as myself, and requesting the `friends_photos` permission
- try to get a list of a friend's albums, using `/joe.bloggs?fields=albums`

all i get as a result is something like:

```
{
   "id": "12345678"
}
```

ie, no albums! i am definitely a friend of joe bloggs on facebook, and i can browse his albums using the web site.

am i missing something?

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe the friend doesn’t share his photos with apps others are using.

Comment: ok, so where does one set the flag that says "i share this album with other (potentially unknown) apps"?

Comment: You don’t share an album individually, you make general settings for what apps that your friends are using can access in your privacy settings.